# How would this snippet translate to Haskell?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, iteration

I'm struggling with Haskell, and the idea of using recursion to iterate over things.

For instance, how would

```
// this might seem silly but I need to do it
list1 = empty list
list2 = list of numbers
for i from 0 to N // N being a positive integer
    for each number in list2
        if number == i, add to list1
```

translate into the 'functional paradigm'? Any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Going step by step:

> ```
> list2 = list of numbers
> ```

We'll take this as a given, so `list2` is still just a list of numbers.

> ```
> for i from 0 to N // N being a positive integer
> ```

The correct way to do this in Haskell is generally with a list. Laziness means that the values will be computed only when used, so traversing a list from 0 to N ends up being the same thing as the loop you have here. So, just `[0..n]` will do the trick; we just need to figure out what to do with it.

> ```
> for each number in list2
> ```

Given "for each" we can deduce that we'll need to traverse the entirety of `list2` here; what we do with it, we don't know yet.

> ```
> if number == i, add to list1
> ```

We're building `list1` as we go, so ideally we want that to be the final result of the expression. That also means that at each recursive step, we want the result to be the `list1` we have "so far". To do that, we'll need to make sure we pass each step's result along as we go.

So, getting down to the meat of it:

The `filter` function finds all the elements in a list matching some predicate; we'll use `filter (== i) list2` here to find what we're after, then append that to the previous step's result. So each step will look like this:

```
step :: (Num a) => [a] -> a -> [a]
step list1 i = list1 ++ filter (== i) list2
```

That handles the inner loop. Stepping back outwards, we need to run this for each value `i` from the list `[0..n]`, with the `list1` value being passed along at each step. This is exactly what fold functions are for, and in this case `step` is exactly what we need for a left fold:

```
list2 :: (Num a) => [a]
list2 = -- whatever goes here...

step :: (Num a) => [a] -> a -> [a]
step list1 i = list1 ++ filter (== i) list2

list1 :: (Num a) => a -> [a]
list1 n = foldl step [] [0..n]
```

If you're wondering where the recursion is, both `filter` and `foldl` are doing that for us. As a rule of thumb, it's usually better to avoid direct recursion when there are higher-level functions to do it for you.

---

That said, the algorithm here is silly in multiple ways, but I didn't want to get into that because it seemed like it would distract from your actual question more than it would help.

Comment: Why not use `concatMap` instead of folding over an explicit concatenation step?

Comment: Note that in this case, you can use list comprehension: [number|i<-[1..N],number<-list2,i==number] which is direct translation of your pseudo-code.

Comment: Thanks for a great answer. I realize that the snippet I posted is bizarre... I drastically shaved any meaning away from it. It's part of a radix sort exercise I am doing.

Comment: Let's say that instead of list2 being a list of numbers, it's a list of lists of numbers. Provided I know which location within each list I need to be checking, does your solution still hold?

Comment: @bdonlan: Because I figured the question was looking for general approaches to using functional style rather than direct implementation, and a fold is the more generic approach. The whole concatenating thing is silly anyway, and if I was improving the algorithm I'd go a lot farther than just using `concatMap`.

Comment: @chrislegend: The general *form* of my solution is, indeed, quite general, as stated in my previous comment. I suspect that *in practice* what you're actually doing warrants something very different, though, because Haskell lists are basically linked lists, and very inefficient for indexing and searching (as opposed to iteration and stack-like algorithms, where they're quite effective).

Comment: @chrislegend: In other words, I'm afraid you may have shaved *too much* meaning away from the snippet, and that the real translation to functional (and specifically Haskell-like) style needs to happen a couple layers higher in the actual code.

Comment: I think you are exactly right. I'm having a little trouble breaking out of my imperative shell. What advice would you give me on implementing a radix sort on a set of n-tuples, where each tuple element has maximum value D?

Comment: @chrislegend: The n-tuples here being homogeneous lists? Because dealing with actual tuples, i.e. `(1, 2, 5)` is very different.

Comment: @chrislegend: What level of "hand-rolled implementation" are you interested in? The correct answer for most real code would be "find a trie library, put them in that, read them off in order", since roughly speaking a trie is to a radix sort what a conventional search tree is to a comparison sort, and they're also one of the best ways to have an "updatable by index" collection in pure code. But as a learning exercise that's not terribly helpful. Would you rather a better, but still simple and list-based version? You could also try to implement a simple trie yourself.

Answer (score 10):

Sorry, but I can't help but use a better algorithm...

```
let goodNumber n = (0 <= n && n < N)
let list1 = sort (filter goodNumber list2)
```

---

Edit: In hindsight this is a little bit of overkill, since the OP was trying to implement a sorting algo in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

```
let list1 = sort [a | a<-list2, a>=0, a<=N]
```

`a<-list2` picks up each number of list2
`a>=0, a<=N` check if the picked number meets ALL these conditions
if conditions are met, a is put into a new list
Once all the elements of list2 have been thus checked and put into a new list, we do a sort on this
Resulting list is assigned to list1